# How to generate multiple stars using CIStarShineGenerator?

Tags: swift, core-image

I'm looking for efficient way to generate multiple stars at random places (for example 10-15 of them). With this code below I can easily achieve one star but my question would be how to generate more than one star.

```
let filter = StarShineGenerator()
filter.center = CIVector(values: [CGFloat.random(in: 50.0...finalImage.size.width), CGFloat.random(in: 50.0...finalImage.size.height)], count: 2)
let ciFilter = filter.filter()
guard let ciFilter = ciFilter else { return }
let result = ciFilter.outputImage
guard let result = result else { return }
finalImage = UIImage(cgImage: context.createCGImage(result, from: CIImage(image: finalImage)!.extent)!)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CIStarShineGenerator` creates a single starburst. If you want to generate lots of them, you'd have to call it repeatedly and composite the resulting images together.

Core Image also has compositing filters that will combine images; you could use one of those to combine your different starbursts. I don't know if it would be fast enough.

You might also install your image into multiple CALayers, apply rotation and shift transforms to those layers, add them to the backing layer of a UIView, and then capture the combined view's contents into an image.

Comment: It's very weird that you can't generate multiple items at the same time. I've already tried calling this function multiple times and it's just not usable because of the memory issues. Maybe I should generate those stars on the smaller image to boost the performance but I don't know. I will try to find a way right now to at least chain those CIFilter effects although it's not very easy since I believe it always generates stars on the blank UIImage. Hmmmm.